# Messagebox.show method not working with an int variable?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datatable

My WPF application contains a form which when loaded, obtains two variables which contain a PID (**procid**) and a processname (**procname**) of a certain process currently running on the local computer.

I have a data table which contains `netstat -ano` data outputs in each column. Now i will need to compare either (**procid**) or (**procname**) with the associated data contained in the datatable, if both variable matches, store the current index/row number and use that index to get the remote ip address (**remoteIp**) of the associated datarow to be stored as variables.

But for some reason when i try to test the variable **remoteIp** the messagebox does not show up or just displays nothing. Is there something wrong with my code?

**Pageone.xaml.cs**

```
    public partial class Pageone : Page
    {

        public Pageone(MainWindow mainWindow)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        private string remoteIp;


        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {


            //instantiate the MainWindow and assign it to the 'window' variable

            var window = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
            string procName = window.proc1;
            int subprocPid = window.proc2;
            string procPID = subprocPid.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(procPID);


            using (Process ns = new Process())
            {

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[] {
                    new DataColumn("Protocol"),
                    new DataColumn("Local Address"),
                    new DataColumn("Foreign Address"),
                    new DataColumn("State"),
                    new DataColumn("PID"),
                    new DataColumn("Process Name"),
                });

                ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("netstat.exe", "-ano");
                psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                psi.UseShellExecute = false;
                ns.StartInfo = psi;
                // Run it, and read the results
                ns.Start();
                using (StreamReader r = ns.StandardOutput)
                {
                    string output = r.ReadToEnd();
                    ns.WaitForExit();

                    //Parse those results into a DataTable, polling the Process info
                    string[] lines = output.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);


                    foreach (string line in lines)
                    {
                        string[] elements = line.Split(' ');
                        if (elements.Length < 5) continue;
                        if (elements.Contains("Proto")) continue;

                        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

                        List<string> validElements = new List<string>();

                        //Weed out empty elements.
                        foreach (string element in elements)
                        {
                            //skip blanks
                            if (element.Trim() == "") continue;
                            validElements.Add(element);
                        }

                        foreach (string element in validElements)
                        {

                            foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
                            {
                                // fill in the buckets. Note that UDP doesn't have a state
                                if (dr["Protocol"].ToString() == "UDP" && dc.ColumnName == "State") continue;

                                if (dr[dc] == DBNull.Value)
                                {
                                    dr[dc] = element;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        dr["Process Name"] = Process.GetProcessById(int.Parse(dr["PID"].ToString())).ProcessName;
                        dt.Rows.Add(dr);


                    }

                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {

                        int index = dt.Rows.IndexOf(row);
                        object cellprocPid = row["PID"];
                        object cellprocName = row["Process Name"];
                        object cellprocremoteIp = row["Foreign Address"];



                        if(cellprocPid.ToString() == procPID)
                        {
                            //MessageBox.Show(dt.Rows[index]["Process Name"].ToString());
                            //MessageBox.Show(index.ToString());
                            remoteIp = dt.Rows[index]["Foreign Address"].ToString();
                        }



                    }
                }
            }


            MessageBox.Show(remoteIp);
     }
}
```

Comment: There are several issues with your code, but as a first step you should place a breakpoint at `remoteIp = dt.Rows[index]["Foreign Address"].ToString();` line and see if it is even ever hit.

Comment: Also, the `foreach` loop already gives you access to the `row` object, you do not need the `Index` variable at all.

Comment: Plus, you should consider using Typed Datasets instead of untyped ones. They give you several compile-time benefits like type checking, avoiding typos etc.

Comment: Okay so I've put the break point on the if statement and it seems like the if statement condition did not match, thus not executing the code within it. 

But how would i get the current index of the row if i don't use the index variable?

I guess i will look into using typed datasets but will it work in the context of getting the data from netstat? Thanks.

Comment: Answer to your first question is that you do not need the Index because you already have the `row` itself. Answer to your second question is that Typed DataSets are proper super-set of untyped DataSets. They just add strongly-typed wrapper properties to access individual attributes of row. So Typed Datasets provide every functionality that an untyped Dataset can provide, plus some more.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the if statement condition did not match due to both of the variable having different process Id's, which resulting in the messagebox displaying nothing.